# how to read text from a file and input it to a variable

Tags: c, clion

i'm civil engineering student, and yes, of course it's not programming related major. i'm making an app for calculating "soil strength" that cant be calculated with excel.

so i have already made algorithm for my app, and i want try to put float value in an float array by reading a .txt file.

example, this is the content of my .txt file:

```
12
12.5
16.3
13.4
17.4
14.3
25.6
25.2
12.5
63.5
```

just a simple .txt file, and i want to assign every number into an array. but, i don't know how. the number of number in that .txt file is uncertain, it could be contain 20 numbers, 36 numbers etc. i've read how to read a file from a book, but it cant read a whole file with uncertain number of numbers

please help me fix this problem, so all my friend could finish a task easily. thanks!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but, i'm using C, not C++. will my C code works?

Comment: "will my C code works?" --> There is no posted C code.

Comment: @chux but i have given a "C" tag in my question, not C++

Comment: Check [here](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html). Putting it in a loop with an array of _malloc_ ed pointers should be straightforward.

Comment: Is there a reason you're tied to c? 
You could look up 'Dynamic Arrays in C' and make your own implementation, but I think it would be easier just to use a higher-level language

Comment: Perhaps an English issue. "my C code" implies code that _you_ wrote.  There is none posted.

Comment: Another solution would be to make an extra large array, and pad the extra space.

Or have one pass through the text file to count the number of elements, and then make the array, and then save it.

Comment: An approach is to read the numbers into a linked-list.  Then convert the link-list into an array.

Comment: @chux wow, so how could Vini89 and Dustin Ryan-Roespsch know i'm using C? They're must be a magician!

Comment: Then again, "an approach" is to start with `fopen` and go from there. I have no idea what OP's question is. (Well unless it's "sumbody write me some code".)

Comment: @DustinRyan-Roepsch i've tried to code in python, but python always give a strange bug. like if i input the number consecutively from smaller to larger there's no error. but, if i input the number randomly, the error appear. so i decide to code in C haha

Comment: @FDuldul To be honest it may be easier to figure out what was wrong with your python program than to reimplement it like this in C. Python is more expressive with less code, and also comes with a lot of built in options for file I/O, lists, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is no code in the question, so we can't say if it will work or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is fairly basic. Since you are reading some unknown number of `float`s, allocate memory for some reasonably expected amount. Read floats from the file into your array until you reach that limit, then reallocate additional space as needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NFLTS 64

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    float *fltarr = NULL;
    size_t i = 0, nflts = NFLTS;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    /* allocate NFLTS floats initially */
    if (!(fltarr = malloc (NFLTS * sizeof *fltarr))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* for each float in file */
    while (fscanf (fp, "%f", &fltarr[i]) == 1) {
        if (i + 1  == nflts) {   /* check if limit reached - realloc */
            void *tmp = realloc (fltarr, sizeof *fltarr * nflts * 2);
            if (!tmp) { /* if realloc fails, use existing data */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc memory exhausted.\n");
                break;
            }
            fltarr = tmp; /* assign realloced block to fltarr */
            nflts *= 2;   /* update nflts */
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);  /* close input if not stdin */

    nflts = i;      /* save number of floats in array as nflts */

    for (i = 0; i < nflts; i++) /* output floats in fltarr */
        printf (" fltarr[%2zu] : %.2f\n", i, fltarr[i]);

    free (fltarr);  /* free allocated memory */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_fltdyn dat/fltarr.txt
 fltarr[ 0] : 12.00
 fltarr[ 1] : 12.50
 fltarr[ 2] : 16.30
 fltarr[ 3] : 13.40
 fltarr[ 4] : 17.40
 fltarr[ 5] : 14.30
 fltarr[ 6] : 25.60
 fltarr[ 7] : 25.20
 fltarr[ 8] : 12.50
 fltarr[ 9] : 63.50
```

(note: rarely is the `scanf` family of functions recommended for reading lines of data. This is one exception where you are guaranteed a fixed format on each line where using them makes sense.)

Look it over and let me know if you have further questions. (B.S. Aero `89 TAMU)

Comment: Nicely done.  Good use of `realloc()`.

Comment: Even a blind squirrel finds a nut every once in a while... Thanks `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use scanf to read each of the numbers (until you reach the end of file). You need dynamic memory allocation since you don't know the number of floats in the file in advance. The example below opens a file named "filename" and does exactly what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *in;

    size_t count = 0;
    size_t array_size = 16;
    double *array;

    in = fopen("filename", "r");
    if (!in)
        return -1;

    array = malloc(array_size * sizeof(*array));
    if (!array)
    {
        fclose(in);
        return -1;
    }

    while (fscanf(in, "%lf", array + count) == 1)
    {
        count += 1;
        if (count == array_size)
        {
            double *temp;

            array_size *= 2;
            temp = realloc(array, array_size);
            if (!temp)
            {
                free(array);
                fclose(in);
                return -1;
            }
            array = temp;
        }
    }

    free(array);
    fclose(in);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice use of `realloc()` here. A good way to go.  (Little indication of success or failure though)  Comparing against `==1` better than `!= EOF` (infinite loop on non-numeric input)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#define MAX_LEN 10000
#define FILE_NAME "your-file-path"
int main()
{
    double array[MAX_LEN];
    FILE *fp= fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
    if(!fp)
    {
        perror("Can Not Open The File");
        return 1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%lf", &array[i++]) != EOF)
    {
        if(i == MAX_LEN)
        {
            printf("The file is huge, you should define larger array");
            break;
        }
    }
    int j = 0;
    while(j < i)
        printf("%d: %lf\n", j, array[j++]);    
}
```

Comment: 1) Off by 1.  `i++` should be in `while()` loop.  2) `fscanf(fp, "%lf", &array[i++]) == 1` is better.  With non-numeric input, eventually code will have UB.  Better to quit early